# Regex that matches all digits after "pid-" in a URL

Tags: regex

I'm looking for an regex that returns everything after `pid-` in this example URL.

- URL:

  www.example.com/bla-pid-123456
- Expected match:

  123456

Comment: Simply [`(?<=pid-)\d+`](http://regex101.com/r/sZ4zN6/1)

Comment: I assume you've read relevant documentation, like: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html ?

Comment: *Have you ever tried something? Answerers, please... scoring shouldn't kill qualities.*

Comment: @OlegKomarov `\K` is generally faster than the explicit look-behind. Not all regex engines support either construct, though, and the OP didn't specify an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

### Using PCRE-Compatible Grep

```
$ echo 'www.example.com/bla-pid-123456' | pcregrep -o 'pid-\K\d+'
123456
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile('pid-(\d+)$')
>>> m = pat.search('www.example.com/bla-pid-123456')
>>> m.groups()[0]
'123456'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this: (in swift because i don't know which language you use):

```
func findStringAfterFirstOccurenceOfString(stringToFind: NSString, inString stringToSearch: NSString) -> NSString?
    for (var i = 0, i <= stringToSearch.length - stringToFind.length; i++) {
        let range = NSMakeRange(i, stringToFind.length)
        let sub = stringToSearch.substringWithRange(range)
        if sub == stringToFind {
            return stringToSearch.substringFromIndex(i + stringToFind.length)
        }
    }
    return nil // No occurrence found
}
```

`stringToFind` would be "pid-" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know if you can acccept alpha and/or numberic after the PID, I have this. mileage may vary.

in javascript

just for alphanumberic:

```
var str = "www.example.com/bla-pid-123456",
    re = /pid[-](\w+)$/ ,
    val = str.match(re) ? str.match(re)[1] : null;
```

note: I explicitly capture ONLY if its "pid-.....", otherwise I assign null to "val". This is a bit more what you might need, but since I do not know your intent, and the url can have 'gig-asdfasdf', or 'whatever-whater'... I want something explicit.

Comment: What do you think `[^pid-]` match?

Comment: `[^pid-]` means `not include '-' ,'p' ,'i' ,'d' `, NOT `not include   'pid-'` . in this case, just `/[^-](\w)+$/` is enough.

Comment: yeah. I dig. I'll edit in a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      var result = 'www.example.com/bla-pid-123456'.match(/.*pid-(\d+)/);
      result = (result) ? result[1] : "";
```